# Converting ../ in paths in Ant

Tags: ant

I have an Ant build that has this line in it:

`WORKSPACE.dir = ${basedir}/../`

I then have:

`CORE_PROJECT.dir= ${WORKSPACE.dir}/UUI_Core`

which means that I end up with paths like this:

`C:\dev\workspaces\RTC\UUI_Core_ANT/..//UUI_Core`

This works fine in almost all cases but I am trying to build a list of classes to be used in a build. At the moment I have this code:

```
<pathconvert 
    property="coreClasses" 
    pathsep=" " 
    dirsep="." 
    refid="coreSources">
    <map from="C:\dev\workspaces\RTC\UUI_Core\src\" to="" />
    <mapper>
        <chainedmapper>
            <globmapper from="*.mxml" to="*"/>
        </chainedmapper>
        <chainedmapper>
            <globmapper from="*.as" to="*"/>
        </chainedmapper>
    </mapper>
</pathconvert>
```

Which does the job of removing the file location and jsut leaving the package structure. It is not very flexible though. I should be able to use CORE_PROJECT.dir here.

So, how can I convert

`C:\dev\workspaces\RTC\UUI_Core_ANT/..//UUI_Core`

to

`C:\dev\workspaces\RTC\UUI_Core`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
WORKSPACE.dir = ${basedir}/../
```

This is not a valid Ant syntax.

To convert `..` you should use `location` attribute of the `<property>` task instead of `value`. `location` substitutes the attribute value with an absolute path.  In your case:

```
<property name="WORKSPACE.dir" location="${basedir}/.."/>
```

**EDIT**: I should add, **always** use `location` attribute when setting path-like properties.